# Most fastest way to find rows in one table which are not present in other table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, azure-functions

I have 2 tables , one called "Booking" and another called "Assignments" there is no relation between these two tables

"Booking" tables contains columns "Resource" ,"start date", "end date", "hours"

"Assignments" table contains columns  "Resource" , "start date" , "end date", "hours"

"Booking" table rows are daily records , means start and end date will always be same and hours will be less than 8(working hours in a day)

"Assignment" table rows can be multi day records , means start and end date can be same or different , example start date 01-02-2022 and end date 03-02-2022 and hours can be 24 hours(max 8 hours per day)

Now I have to find all booking rows for a "Resource" , which do not have equivalent assignment row for a particular day and hours

There can be complex scenario in which booking for "resource a" for "1-2-2022" is for "8 hours" , but assignment row for same date and resource is just 6 hours , so I need to find those missing hours too.

What is the fastest and most efficient way to do it? Records can be in millions and preferred programming language is C# , if C# cannot give me a way to process all this in Max 30 minutes ,other approaches are also welcome , like storing these 2 tables in a SQL database and run a query on it  , to get results in a 3rd table

Thanks for your help

Comment: Any reason why you prefer to do it in C#?

Comment: this is just a small part of a bigger logic , that is already written in C# and these tables are stored in Sass application , so i cannot access Db and can only get the data through an API exposed by the application , so running a query directly on Db is not a possibility

Comment: but I can take this data to Azure SQL storage and then run a SQL query on it , but that is definitely my last option , as business is concerned about data security ,getting this stored in another database will trigger a long chain of approvals.

Comment: The "most fastest" way is to have the database do data-related operations. Anything else is going to require pulling *all* the data out into the application, so you don't need an RDBMS, a text file would be better :)

Comment: _so i cannot access Db and can only get the data through an API_ Then start by having a discussion with the entire team about your requirements. All these restrictions you post in comments is  not an efficient or effective way to address your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the backend to do such processes.
An index on a Checksum on each table would be efficient.
Start by creating the Booking and Assignment tables.

Add the checksums:

```
ALTER TABLE Booking
ADD Booking_Checksum AS CHECKSUM( [Resource] ,[start date], [end date], [hours]) PERSISTED;

ALTER TABLE Assignment
ADD Assignment_Checksum AS CHECKSUM( [Resource] ,[start date], [end date], [hours]) PERSISTED;
```

Add indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Booking_Checksum] ON [dbo].[Booking]
(   Booking_Checksum ASC )

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Assignment_Checksum] ON [dbo].[Assignment]
(   Assignment_Checksum ASC )
```

All in Booking but not Assignment:

```
Select b.*
From Booking b
left join Assignment a on b.Booking_Checksum = a.Assignment_Checksum 
where a.Assignment_Checksum is null
```

All in Assignment but not in Booking:

```
Select a.*
From Assignment a
left join Booking b on b.Booking_Checksum = a.Assignment_Checksum 
where b.Booking_Checksum is null
```

Comment: thanks cloudsafe for the answer ,Looks like a good approach , but i think it might not meet the requirement completely , until or unless i break down assignment rows to per day rows , as booking rows are also per day rows , another scenario which might not be fulfilled is of finding the remaining hours , for example booking row have data as "resource a"  "1-1-2022" , "1-1-2022" and "6 hours" , but assignment might have data as "resource a" , "1-1-2022" , "1-1-2022" and "2 hours" , i need to get remaining 4 hours from this